# get current default_target_path inside an controller

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using FOSUserBundle+FOSFacebookBundle and I'm trying to make my login and register page unaccesible after logging in. If the user logged in and is accesing one of these page he should be redirected to page defined in firewall's default_target_path.

The problem is that I don't know how to get default_target_path while inside an controller. I was using

```
$request->getSession()->get('_security.target_path');
```

but it returns null.

Here is my security.yml file:

```
jms_security_extra:
    secure_all_services: false
    expressions: true

security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        chainprovider:
            chain:
                providers: [ fos_userbundle, fos_facebookbundle]
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username
        fos_facebookbundle:
            id: fos_facebookbundle

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                default_target_path: /
            fos_facebook:
                app_url: "FB_APP_URL"
                server_url: "APP_URL"
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_fb_check
                default_target_path: /
                provider: fos_facebookbundle
            logout: true
            anonymous: true

        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js|font)/
            security: false

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            # ...
            default_target_path: %target_path%
```

target_path set in `parameters.yml`

```
parameters:
    # ...
    target_path: /
    # ...
```

and than get value by:

```
$this->container->getParameter('target_path');
```

Comment: Yes, this is a solution too, but any ideas on how to get the actual default_target_path? Thanks.

Comment: `firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            # ...
            default_target_path: %target_path%
            always_use_default_target_path: true`

Everytime after login, user will be redirect to default_actual_path.

Comment: There's a typo on the last line:  taget_path should be target_path  Wish I could just edit it but StackOverflow only allows edits of 6 characters or more

Answer (score 1):

You miss a part in the get:

```
$request->getSession()->get('_security.main.target_path');
```